# How to convert any input XML file to similar Java object structure?

Tags: java

Hi all can any one tell me is it possible to convert any XML file file to equivalent java object using java?

Answer (score 2):

You want a DOM parser. There are many around, a Google search for "Java DOM parser" will help you. Take [this page](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) for example.

Comment: Again in DOM also we are specifying root element name. But in my case i don't what kind of XML file user will give. I mean I will not be knowing contents of XML file. I am looking for soln which is can convert any XML structure to equivalent java object

Comment: You don't need to know what the contents is. You don't need to tell the parser the root element name. Read the page I linked and try it out, it describes exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for [JAXB](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnazf.html).

Comment: JAXB is good if you have a specific XML schema that describes your documents and you want to generate schema-specific Java accessor objects.

Comment: But its not specific XML schema file. It can be any XML file.

Answer (score 1):

Use XStream library it is quite simple:
http://x-stream.github.io/tutorial.html

```
                // object -> XML -> File 
    XStream xstream = new XStream(driver);
    String data = xstream.toXML(metaData);

                //  XML -> object
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
    YourClass obj = (UourClass)xstream.fromXML(jSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use **unmarshall** function in [castor](http://www.castor.org).

Comment: Yes. Castor mapping is easy option. You can transform Java Object from XMl as well as XML from Java object.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add another to the collection.

Have a look at the [Apache Jakarta Digester](http://commons.apache.org/digester/) this is what Tomcat uses to automap XML files (like server.xml).